# How to create instances from Array values

Tags: rust

I'm quite new to rust and used to write code in other languages like JavaScript. My project is to code a program to control a cc2500 chip from my raspberry pi via rppal crate in Rust. So far it works but I'm searching for the right way.

**Given**: I have a list of unsigned 8bit integers and need a list of [Segments](https://docs.rs/rppal/0.11.3/rppal/spi/struct.Segment.html) with delay 20.

**In JavaScript** I would do it like this

```
let bytes = [0x7F, 0x55, ...]

let segments = bytes.map(byte => {
    let segment = Segment.with_write([byte]);
    segment.set_delay(20);
    return segment;
});

this.spi.transfer_segments(segments);
```

**In rust** I tried it like this

```
let bytes = vec![0x7F, 0x55, ...];

let mut segments:Vec<Segment> = vec![];
for (i, byte) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
    let buffer = [byte.clone()];
    segments[i] = Segment::with_write(&buffer);
    segments[i].set_delay(20);
}

let written = self.spi.transfer_segments(&segments)
    .expect("Could not write to SPI bus");
```

But I always struggle with the ownership rules. **How would you do this or what is the best practice?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all of your slices happen to be unary, you can use [`std::slice::from_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html) to create them, pointing to the bytes from your `bytes` vector:

```rust
let bytes = vec![0x7F, 0x55, ...];

let segments = bytes.iter().map(|byte| {
    let buffer = std::slice::from_ref(byte);
    let mut segment = Segment::with_write(buffer);
    segment.set_delay(20);
    segment
});

let segments: Vec<_> = segments.collect().

let written = self.spi.transfer_segments(&segments)
    .expect("Could not write to SPI bus");
```